# Update count in growing table using php in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

table sample :

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| source | target | count |
+--------+--------+-------+
| cat    | dog    |  NULL |
| dog    | cat    |  NULL |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

MySQL code :

```
update test set count = count+1 where source ='dog' and target='cat';
```

the count columns must be `1` after execute this MySQL code, but it never works,
shall we give an initial value to `count`? this table could grow up every second, so that I can't use `COUNT(*)` solve this question, any suggestion?

Comment: dont keep that null, by default keep the value to 0, define it 0

Comment: Don't store it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `alter` your table and set a `default` value, `0`. You can use `modify` or `change` (you should replace `int` with your datatype):

```
alter table `tbl` modify column `count` int not null default 0;
```

Comment: Is this method could be use in growing up table?

Comment: @yihanghwang: I don't see any obstacles you can encounter. At first you should update existing records with `update tbl set count = 0 where count is null` and then run the command above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE` to make the `NULL` a zero.

```
update test set count = coalesce(count,0)+1 where source ='dog' and target='cat';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IFNULL` to change `null` value to `0`,

```
update test set count = IFNULL(count, 0) +1 where source ='dog' and target='cat';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data type of count but will answer you as to make it int with default 0 and then update with increment with the same query. If query may have some problem, print it on front & execute on back end..it will be solved..